AKS Primality-Testing Algorithm
The first step of the AKS algorithm tests an odd input value $n$ for exponentiality:
if $n = a^b$ for some integers $a$ and $b$ then return "Composite".
How can $n$ be tested for exponentiality?

To determine whether $n = a^b$ for some integers $a$ and $b$, you can use binary search. Observe that if $n = a^b$, then $b \leq \log_2(n)$. For each $k \in \{2, 3, \dots, \lceil \log_2(n) \rceil\}$, perform a binary search in the range $[2, n]$ to check whether there exists a number $i$ such that $i^k$ is equal to $n$.
The time complexity is $O(\log_2(n)^3)$ because

Computing $i^k$ takes $O(\log_2(n))$ times.  While more efficient methods like repeated squaring could reduce this, the bound is sufficient for our analysis.
Performing binary search over the range $[2,n]$ requires $O(\log_2(n))$ steps.
The loop for $k$ iterates at most $\log_2(n)$ times, since $k \leq \log_2(n)$.


@hello It does not matter. The time complexity for the binary search would still be $O(\log_2(n))$.


How can n be tested for exponentiality?

Well, the most straight-forward approach is to compute $\sqrt[b]{n}$ for prime $b$ until either you hit an integer or a value less than two.  This is not especially cheap [1], however it is far less costly than the rest of the AKS algorithm.
It might be tempting to use the Enhanced Miller Rabin test (which is considerably more efficient); however that is guaranteed to catch only prime powers, not necessarily the powers of composite numbers).

[1]: One optimization that comes to mind is to first approximate $\sqrt[b]{n}$ using floating point, and skip that $b$ if that's not close to an integer, and use it as a starting point for Newton-Raphson if it is.

The 2-adic variant from §21 of Bernstein avoids having to deal with floating-point complexity. In the context of primality testing, it is safe to assume the input is either 2 or odd.
